# how to auto read OTP SMS code in react js app

Tags: reactjs, webotp-api

Iam working in reactjs login page with otp code login.
I want to auto-fill my OTP.
I used The code below but there is no response for navigator.credential.get() in my app
could any one help me how to fix this.

```
   const handleOtpRetrieval = () => {
        const ac = new AbortController()
        navigator.credentials.get({
            otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
            signal: ac.signal
        }).then(otp => {
            alert(`got otp from client===>${otp}`)
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(`err: ${err}`)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
            /**OTPConnection**/
            if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
                handleOtpRetrieval()
            }
        }
    }, [])
```

sms format:

OTP:123456

@domain.info #123456

working on https and sms format rules passed and
try above code return no alert in my code